# How to look up C function in emacs which does not belongs to a class?

Tags: c++, c, emacs, cedet

So far, I was able to call member functions which belong to a class for a struct. CEDET can give the suggestion nicely. However, for non-member functions, such as functions in C, which usually does not belong to anything i.e. functions like sort, qsort.... I can only auto-complete with CEDET if I have an instance of a class/struct. Without it, I have to type the function manually.

Is there a way to have code suggestion for such functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEDET works fine for such functions - you need to be sure, that all necessary headers are included into your source code.  You can also force CEDET to re-parse buffer with `M-x bovinate` command.  But it's better to use CEDET from bzr repository, because fixes for C & C++ mode are made very often.

If it still don't working look to output of `M-x semantic-analyze-debug-assist` command, and post results to cedet-devel list